# Cannot find the declaration of element 'assignments'

Tags: xml, schema

So I am beginning with XML and Schemas and I ran across this today and I have not been able to figure it out.

I am getting and error that says,

> Ln 5 Col 2 : Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'assignments'.

I believe I have declared the element, but perhaps I am missing something and have not.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assignments
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    SchemaLocation="A3.xsd"
>
    <assignment id="a1">
        <name>Schemas</name>
        <page>110</page>
    </assignment>

    <assignment id="a2">
        <name>Namespaces</name>
        <page>258</page>
        <files>names.xml</files>
        <files>names.dtd</files>
    </assignment>

    <assignment id="a3">
        <name>RELAX NG</name>
        <page>305</page>
        <files>account.xml</files>
        <files>customers.xml</files>
        <files>finance.xsd</files>
    </assignment>

</assignments>
```

This is my Schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:target="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns" elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
<element name="assignments" type="target:TypeAssignments"></element>

<complexType name="TypeAssignments">
    <sequence>
        <element name="assignment" type="target:assignmentInfo"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="id" type="string" use="required"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="assignmentInfo">
    <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"></element>
            <element name="page" type="target:TypePage"></element>
            <element name="file" type="target:TypeFile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="TypePage">
    <restriction base="integer">
        <minInclusive value="50" />
        <maxInclusive value="498" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="TypeFile">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value=".xml" />
        <enumeration value=".dtd" />
        <enumeration value=".xsd" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

</schema>
```

As I am still learning, feel free to point out any other mistakes I may have made not related to the problem.

Thanks
Levi

Comment: You shouldn't assign http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance as your default namespace, because then it is considered to be the namespace for all elements in your XML whose namespace hasn't been explicitly specified. Assign http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance it to a different namespace, like the commonly used xmlns:xsi.

Comment: If I set it up like that, will I need to specify an element type like this: type="xsi:string"?

Comment: Yes. 
By the way, in XSD schema's usually xs is used, and xsi in the XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that I was not declaring my main element 'assignments' as a *complex element*, I actually wasn't declaring it as anything at all.

So by taking this line from my schema file:

```
<element name="assignment" type="target:assignmentInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
```

and changing it into this:

```
<element name="assignments">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="assignment" type="target:assignmentInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

The element was properly defined, thanks for the help everyone.

Levi

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  I took out some of the extra details of the schema element, but with a little tweaking something like the following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">        
  <xs:element name="assignments" type="TypeAssignments" />    
  <xs:complexType name="TypeAssignments">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="assignment" type="assignmentInfo" 
          minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>        
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="assignmentInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="page" type="TypePage" />
      <xs:element name="files" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>   

  <xs:simpleType name="TypePage">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="50" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="498" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="TypeFile">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value=".xml" />
      <xs:enumeration value=".dtd" />
      <xs:enumeration value=".xsd" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Notes**:

1. The ID attribute has been moved from `TypeAssignments` to `assignmentInfo`.
2. All types and element names have been prefixed with the namespace `xs`
3. I've added the minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes for the assignment elements.  Otherwise, only a single assignment element is allowed within assignments.
4. I've auto-closed your elements using "/>" instead of ""  Not necessary, but a bit less typing to do.

All in all, I didn't modify all that much so you have the right idea.

Comment: I understand why using the xs: prefix as a namespace is used.  Would it be easier for me to declare a namespace as being used in the xml file so I don't have to prefix all of the elements in the schema with xs:?  So if I say something like <assignment id="a2" xmlns="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns">

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to prefix the elements with xs because the types (e.g., string, element, enumeration, etc.) are defined as part of separate schema.

Comment: What if at the top of the schema I declare rather than <xs:schema xlmns:xs...>  just say <schema xmlns:...>  then will that become the default schema for the page?  For my other elements I would specify another schema in the opening <schema> tag like so :
xmlns:target="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns"
targetNamespace="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns" elementFormDefault="qualified"

and then use target:assignmentInfo and so forth for the attribute values I created.

Comment: I tried this, by setting the the top level xmlns:xs="..." attribute to xmlns="..."  It seems to work, but it will get messy when referring to your target namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In your instance document, as excerpted above, you define the `xmlns` attribute on the `<assignments>` element, and do not elsewhere define a namespace. This means that the namespace of `<assignments>` and all of its descendents is set to "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".

Your schema document, however, specifies a `targetNamespace` value of "http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns". Since the elements in your instance document does not have this namespace, validation fails.

Start by changing your instance document to look like this:

```
<assignments
    xmlns="http://www.levijackson.net/web340/ns"
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are telling me I should do, what you pasted is what I have above.  Also, the targetNamespace is referring to the the second namespace I declare right above it.  Unless I am mistaken as to what/how the targetNamespace works.